# Just installed 16.04 on Intel Nuc Firefox problem

Tags: firefox, internet, connection

I was able to download updates but will not connect with Firefox using linksys wrt1900Ac with wired or wireless connection.I looked at ifconfig Getting ip from router and router shows Nuc on network 
Other computers connect when tested with same wired connection
I am experienced with networking but Ubuntu newbie I believe it may be some OS setting 
I tried the ping command as suggested by chili555 I am getting a normal response on the IP but unknown host response with host names so I guess that indicates a Dns problem I don't know the commands to add or configure this
The Linksys ip is presently configured as the DNS and this is working for a
few other computers

Comment: There are many NUCs. Please specify the computer model and also the wifi brand name and model (in the NUC) in order to help us help you.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` I realize it is impossible to copy and paste the results with no connection, just tell us the last couple of lines of each command. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.